# Ngrok not servicing http requests

Tags: tunnel, ngrok

I've been using ngrok for a while now and today I've fired it up but it doesn't appear to be taking requests... I've confirmed this by looking at the web interface at localhost:4040, which shows no incoming requests. At the moment I'm just seeing this:

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. Their service was down for a bit and is now back up. Try again. It is not in a stable state. So it drops frequently.

Comment: ...just checked and I've managed to connect but still very flaky... Keeps dropping the connection and reconnecting, hopefully it will sort itself out.. Also would've been nice to have some warning - I couldn't find a twitter page or anything for them?

Comment: Agreed. It is in an unstable state right now and it would be nice if they had some kind of dashboard or twitter account to post statuses. Their own site is down as well.